# Rows not being inserted into UITable

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app with a table view that expands/collapses sections, following the example in Apple's [Table View Animations & Gestures sample app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). I am running into problems when an item is added to a closed section: after that, the section no longer opens, and I get an exception when I try to open and then close it.

I've traced this to some strange behaviour in the open/close methods:

```
-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionOpened:(NSInteger)section {

if (![[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section] isOpen]) {

    [[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section] setIsOpen:YES]; 

    NSLog(@"self.tableView: %@", self.tableView);
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger countOfRowsToInsert = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToInsert; i++) {
        [indexPathsToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }

    // Apply the updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    NSLog(@"Count of rows to insert: %d", [indexPathsToInsert count]);
    NSLog(@"Rows before insert: %d", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    NSLog(@"Rows after insert: %d", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

}


-(void)sectionHeaderView:(SectionHeaderView*)sectionHeaderView sectionClosed:(NSInteger)section {

if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section] isOpen]) {

    [[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:section] setIsOpen:NO];

    NSInteger countOfRowsToDelete = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    if (countOfRowsToDelete > 0) {
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfRowsToDelete; i++) {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSLog(@"Count of rows to delete: %d", [indexPathsToDelete count]);
        NSLog(@"Rows before delete: %d", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        NSLog(@"Rows after delete: %d", [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]);

    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
}
```

The log messages show that, on open (insert rows), >0 rows are being inserted, and yet the row count for that section stays 0:

```
2012-03-31 13:36:17.454 QuickList7[5523:fb03] Count of rows to insert: 3
2012-03-31 13:36:17.454 QuickList7[5523:fb03] Rows before insert: 0
2012-03-31 13:36:17.454 QuickList7[5523:fb03] Rows after insert: 0
```

This sets up an inconsistent state between the table and data source, and then when I try to "collapse" the section, I get the following exception:

```
2012-03-31 13:48:35.783 QuickList7[5523:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid table view update.  The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source.'
```

How can I insert 3 rows, and still end up with 0 rows?

Thanks,

Sasha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! It was actually in the fetchedResultsController's change handler. It was responding to changes to closed sections, which left the table in a bad state, and out of sync with the data source. So I added a check for each update to only insert/delete/update rows if the containing section is open.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
UITableView *tv = self.tView;
switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:newIndexPath.section] isOpen]) {
            [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isOpen]) {
            [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isOpen]) {
            [self configureCell:[tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isOpen]) {
            [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        if ([[sectionHeaderArray objectAtIndex:newIndexPath.section] isOpen]) {
            [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        break;
}

}
```

Comment: Thats a tricky one! I had the same issue and it took me hours to figure out it had something to do with the sections not being expanded.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I've implemented a similar behavior in a very different way because I was running into this type of problem a lot.

I have a table with `MenuNameCell`s, `MenuItemCell`s and a static cell at the bottom. Only one menu is expanded at a time, and tapping a `MenuNameCell` expands or collapses that menu. Since I keep the `MenuNameCell` in its own section and the `MenuItemCell`s in another, I only have to insert/delete entire sections when I reload the table.

Here's my table's data source:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // number of menus, plus 1 if a menu is open, plus 1 static cell
    return [self.restaurant.menus count]+(self.menu != nil ? 1 : 0)+1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // if this section is our selected menu, return number of items, otherwise return 1
    int numberOfRowsInSection = ([self indexPathIsInMenuItemSection:section] ? [[self.menu items] count] : 1);
    return numberOfRowsInSection;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == [tableView numberOfSections]-1) {
        // ... set up and return static cell
    }
    if ([self indexPathIsInMenuItemSection:indexPath.section]) {
        // ... set up and return menu item cell
    } else  {
        // ... set up and return menu name cell
    }
}
```

and my table's delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    // return if it's a static cell
    if (indexPath.section==[tableView numberOfSections]-1)
        return;
    // if it's a menu name cell, close open menu and maybe expand this menu
    if (![self indexPathIsInMenuItemSection:indexPath.section]) {
        BOOL reset = self.menu == m;
        if (reset) [self reloadTableView:self.tableView withMenu:nil animated:YES autoscroll:NO];
        else [self reloadTableView:self.tableView withMenu:m animated:YES autoscroll:YES];
    }
}
```

There were a couple of helpers mentioned in there:

```
- (BOOL)indexPathIsInMenuItemSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // returns YES if section refers to our MenuItemCells
    int indexOfMenu = [self.restaurant getIndexOfMenu:self.menu];
    return indexOfMenu != -1 && section == indexOfMenu+1;
}

- (void)reloadTableView:(UITableView *)tableView withMenu:(Menu *)menu animated:(BOOL)animated autoscroll:(BOOL)autoscroll
{
    int oldIndex = [self.restaurant getIndexOfMenu:self.menu];
    int newIndex = [self.restaurant getIndexOfMenu:menu];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    if (oldIndex != -1) {
        // index of [section for items] is oldIndex+1
        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:oldIndex+1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    if (newIndex != -1) {
        // index for [section for items] is newIndex+1
        [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndex+1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self setMenu:menu];
    } else {
        // no new menu
        [self setMenu:nil];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
    if (autoscroll) [self autoscroll];
}

- (void)autoscroll
{
    if (self.menu != nil) {
        int section = [self.restaurant getIndexOfMenu:self.menu];
        if (section != -1) {
            NSUInteger indexes[] = {section,0};
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:2];
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Since my data is loaded asynchronously elsewhere, I have this controller set up to receive an NSNotification, but it should work just as well to call this on `viewDidAppear`:

```
[self reloadTableView:self.tableView withMenu:self.menu animated:YES autoscroll:YES];
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if I can clarify any of it.

Comment: Thanks Spencer! This is roughly how I expected to have to implement this, before finding the Apple sample code. Hadn't thought to put the title cells and content cells in separate sections, though - good idea. I think I'll hang on before changing my approach, just to see if anyone has other suggestions (because I'm lazy :). But I'll definitely use this as a template if I have to rewrite. Thanks!